# Webscript that would change Firebase database values for every user automatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So in my Firebase database I have stored users. Every user has a key "status" which default value is "0". It changes to "1" after user has done certain things in the app.

I do not really know how to approach so that every time after 24 hours value would be changed back to "0".

Do I need some kind of a web script which can be run in cron? Is there a way to handle this inside my Firebase console?

Comment: Firebase does not have "cron job" functionality. Use their curl commands inside a shell scripts, ran by a cron. Or try the FCM beta.

Comment: FCM -> Cloud Functions for Firebase. Here's an [example that runs a Cloud Function on a schedule](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron), a [blog post explaining how to run cron jobs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html), and a [video accomplishing the same with a difference service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA).